# Unity Runtime Script Instantiation with Default values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameters, instantiation

I couldn't find any topic matching my scenario, so I made a new one.

I have a prefab of type `Light` called `rewardHighlight`.

I have a script called `Reward` which has a parameter `Highlight` and instantiates the Light using `Light rewardHighlight = (Light) Instantiate (Highlight);`.

I used drag and drop to set the default value of `Highlight` parameter of said script to `RewardHighlight` prefab.

When I drag and drop the script onto an object, it works correctly.

When I add `Reward` script at runtime using `gameObject.AddComponent<Reward>();` I'm getting `The thing you want to instantiate is null`.

All help much appreciated!

**@update**

Full code (stripped for clarity):

---

Reward2.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Reward2 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light Highlight;
    private Light rewardHighlight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       rewardHighlight = (Light) Instantiate (Highlight);
       rewardHighlight.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Test.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.AddComponent<Reward2>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

It looks like Unity scripts 'forget' their defaults at runtime.

Comment: "Highlight" is (I believe) a variable, so it should be "highlight".  Please click "edit" and include your code, both the declaration of "highlight" and where you "Instantiate".  Cheers

Comment: Please see update above

Comment: You are adding only script as component. It won't maintain your values as it will treat that as new.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `AddComponent` in `Test.Start` you need to assign a value to the `Highlight` field on the `Reward2` instance returned by `AddComponent`.

For example, your `Test.Start` may look a little like this:

```
void Start()
{
    Reward2 obj = gameObject.AddComponent<Reward2>();
    obj.Highlight = <SOME VALUE>;
}
```

Now, the value assigned to `Highlight` cannot simply be an instance of the `Light` component, e.g.  `obj.Highlight = new Light()`. The reason for this is the `Instantiate` method creates an instance of a game object and not an individual component. If you use `AddComponent<T>` it still creates an instance of a game object, but will automatically locate component of type `T` on the new game object and will return that.

So, in order to make this work you can change the `Test` class to either:

**1)** Expose a field of type `Light`, similar to the `Reward2` class, and assign that field to the `Highlight` property:

```
public Light HighlightPrefab;
...
void Start()
{
    Reward2 obj = gameObject.AddComponent<Reward2>();
    obj.Highlight = HighlightPrefab;
}
```

or

**2)** create a game object in the `Start` method, add a light component to it and then assign that component to the `Highlight` field:

```
void Start()
{
    Reward2 obj = gameObject.AddComponent<Reward2>();

    GameObject gameObjectForLight = new GameObject();
    Light newLight = gameObjectForLight.AddComponent<Light>();

    //  Initialize newLight here

    obj.Highlight = newLight;
}
```

In either case when `Reward2.Start` calls `Instantiate` it will see that the `Highlight` field is a component, it will then get the game object to which the component is attached and it will create a new instance of that game object.